# Android get frame from an RTSP Stream of an IP Camera(PTZ)

Tags: java, android, rtsp, android-ffmpeg

I am developing an app that play an RTSP stream from a camera using VLC, but I have a situation where I need to get frame of the stream without playing it.Kindly suggest the proper way of doing it. kindly recommend the best Library or SDK to achieve this.

I have used MediaMetadataRetriever, but so far no luck. I have also used FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever but the app crashes.

`D/apitrace: apitrace: warning: caught signal 6`

`D/apitrace: call flush from exceptionCallback`

`A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE) in tid 5035 (pool-3-thread-1), pid 4832`

I have used below code.

```
     ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
     Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
          executor.execute(()->{
          Bitmap bitmap;
        try {

            if (mmr == null){
                mmr = new FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever();
            }
            mmr.setDataSource(url);
       
            bitmap = mmr.getFrameAtTime();
            Log.d("BITMAP_IS_DONE",bitmap.toString());
            mmr.release();

            handler.post(()->{
                thumbnailArrays[1].setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            });

        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ie) {
            ie.printStackTrace();
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this

```
implementation 'com.github.am3n:rtsp-client-android:4.1.0'
```

to app build.gradle

use this

https://github.com/am3n/RTSP-Client-Android

you can receive video frame and do whatever you need

regards